# Firebase Firestore limitations free account?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
In there mention firebase free account can read 50,000 documents per day.
But
[image]
in firebase pricing mention upto 1,500,000 documents free. **Is this total limit? Or monthly limit (30 days * 50,000 (day limit)).If it's correct in a month when complete 1,500,000 then should add bank card to firebase?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indicated limits on reads, writes, and deletes are monthly and are enforced daily chunks of 1/30th the indicated amount. So for document reads the free quota is 50,000 document reads per day.

When you reach that limit, read access to your database is blocked until the next day - or until you upgrade to the pay-as-you-go plan.

Comment: okay.. Andalso 1,500,000 limits give for a month limit or full time read limit. If month limit then refresh in end of every month. Am I correct?

Comment: The document read and write limits are enforced daily, so it resets every day.

Comment: okay... I ask about 1,500,000 limitation .Is it for a month limit or total limit bro?

Comment: The indicated limits on document reads is monthly, and enforced in daily chunks of 50,000a.

Comment: That's the answer I want bro... Thank you so much!!! I built a app and I calculate the read count then I got the monthly read count is near to 1,000,000 . Because of that I thought from 2nd month I have to add my bank card.

Comment: After your answer I don't need to add bank card because my application maximum daily read count is 40,000 and total monthly read count is near to 1,000,000.. Thank you again bro!!!